# If $X\sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $Y\mid X \sim \mathrm{Ber}(1-p^{X})$, what would be the distribution of $Y$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-distribution

I know that if $X\sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $Y\mid X \sim \mathrm{Bin}(X,p)$ then $Y\sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda p)$. Is there an analogous case for a conditioned Bernoulli distribution? i.e. a problem like:

"The number of people walking into a room during a single day is distributed $\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$. Each person has an (independent) probability $p$ to eat a piece of cake on the table (If it not already eaten). What is the probability the cake is eaten at the end of a given day?"

Edit - Answer (Still happy to receive feedback) : We can define $Y$ (For the stated question) as the number of people who would have eaten the cake (Giving us $Y\sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda p)$ and we have $$\mathbb{P}\left(\text{"The cake was eaten"}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(Y\geq1\right)=1-\mathbb{P}\left(Y=0\right)=1-\frac{\left(\lambda p\right)^{0}e^{-\lambda p}}{0!}=1-e^{-\lambda p}$$

Comment: Have you tried writing down the series and simplifying it?

Comment: Isn't that $P(Y\geq n)$ where $Y\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda p)$ and $n$ denotes the number of available cake pieces?

Comment: @drhab Not quite sure I understand what you mean. There is a single piece of cake and it is either eaten or it is not

Comment: @H.Rappeport Do you mean $k!$? Also, I would try to go one step further, using the Taylor expansion of $e^{-\lambda}$ and regrouping things, see if a change of indices gives something.

Comment: If there is only one piece of cake (I thought there could be more) then $n=1$. Further Bernoulli(p) is the same as Bin(1,p), so I see no essential difference.